# Additive Jordan decomposition of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a $3 \times 3$ matrix over the real numbers of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{pmatrix},$$

where the $\lambda_i$’s are nonzero.  How to decompose this matrix as a sum of a semisimple and nilpotent matrices that commute with each other?

I can do the case where all the $\lambda_i$’s are equal.  In this case we simply have the diagonal matrix with the $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal as the semisimple part.  How does one get the general case?

Comment: when there is no difficulty finding the eigenvalues (or names for them, at least) you can just take the matrix $A,$ find invertible $P$ that produces  Jordan form as $P^{-1}AP = J = D + N$ with $D$ diagonal and $N$ the nilpotent part with those $1$'s above the diagonal if needed, then return with $A = PDP^{-1} + PNP^{-1}.$ It is a built in feature of the Jordan canonical form that $DN=ND$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We denote the given matrix by
$$
      A
  :=  \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & 1         & 1       \\
                  & \lambda_2 & 1       \\
                  &           & \lambda_2
      \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We determine the Jordan decomposition of $A = S + N$ with $S$ semisimle and $N$ nilpotent by case distinction:

If $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 =: \lambda$ then the Jordan decomposition is given by
$$
    S
  = \begin{pmatrix}
      \lambda &         &         \\
              & \lambda &         \\
              &         & \lambda
    \end{pmatrix}
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
    N
  = \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 1 & 1 \\
        & 0 & 1 \\
        &   & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are pairwise different then $A$ is diagonalizable, and we find that
$$
  S = A
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
  N = 0.
$$

In the case that we only have two distinct eigenvalues, recall that $S$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues, and that the $\lambda_i$-eigenspace of $S$ coincide with the generalized $\lambda_i$-eigenspace of $A$.
We get three subcases:

- Suppose that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 =: \lambda$ and $\lambda_3 =: \mu$, so that
  $$
      A
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 1       & 1   \\
                & \lambda & 1   \\
                &         & \mu
      \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
  with $\lambda \neq \mu$.
  Then the generalized $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$ is given by $\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle$, and for $c := \lambda - \mu \neq 0$ the generalized $\mu$-eigenspace of $A$ is given by $\langle (1-c, -c, c^2) \rangle$.
  With respect to the basis $\mathcal{B} = (e_1, e_2, (1-c, -c, c^2))$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ the semisimple part $S$ is therefore given by the diagonal matrix
  $$
      \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda &         &     \\
                & \lambda &     \\
                &         & \mu
      \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
  Thus we find that
  \begin{align*}
        S
    &=  \begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 1-c \\
          0 & 1 & -c  \\
          0 & 0 & c^2
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda &         &     \\
                  & \lambda &     \\
                  &         & \mu
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 1-c \\
          0 & 1 & -c  \\
          0 & 0 & c^2
        \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
    \\
    &=  \begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 1-c \\
          0 & 1 & -c  \\
          0 & 0 & c^2
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda &         &     \\
                  & \lambda &     \\
                  &         & \mu
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & (c-1)/c^2 \\
          0 & 1 & 1/c       \\
          0 & 0 & 1/c^2
        \end{pmatrix}
    \\
    &=  \begin{pmatrix}
          1 & 0 & 1-c \\
          0 & 1 & -c  \\
          0 & 0 & c^2
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda & 0       & \lambda (c-1)/c^2 \\
          0       & \lambda & \lambda/c         \\
          0       & 0       & \mu/c^2
        \end{pmatrix}
    \\
    &=  \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda & 0       & \lambda(c-1)/c^2 + \mu(1-c)/c^2 \\
          0       & \lambda & \lambda/c - \mu/c               \\
          0       & 0       & \mu
        \end{pmatrix}
     =  \begin{pmatrix}
          \lambda & 0       & (c-1)/c \\
          0       & \lambda & 1       \\
          0       & 0       & \mu
        \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}
  and
  $$
      N
    = A - S
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 1/c \\
          & 0 & 0   \\
          &   & 0
      \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
- The subcases $\lambda_1 = \lambda_3$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$ can be calculated similarly.
  The case $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$ can actually be derived from the above result:
  By applying the matrix transpose to the decomposition
  $$
      \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 1       & 1   \\
                & \lambda & 1   \\
                &         & \mu
      \end{pmatrix}
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 0       & (c-1)/c \\
        0       & \lambda & 1       \\
        0       & 0       & \mu
      \end{pmatrix}
      +
      \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 1/c \\
          & 0 & 0   \\
          &   & 0
      \end{pmatrix}
    $$
  we arrive at the decomposition
  $$
      \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu & 1       & 1       \\
            & \lambda & 1       \\
            &         & \lambda
      \end{pmatrix}
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        \mu & 1       & (c-1)/c \\
        0   & \lambda & 0       \\
        0   & 0       & \lambda
      \end{pmatrix}
      +
      \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 1/c \\
          & 0 & 1   \\
          &   & 0
      \end{pmatrix}.
    $$
  Here we use that the matrix transpose preserves diagonalizability, nilpotence and commutativity.
  By I’m not sure if there is a nice way to derive the case $\lambda_1 = \lambda_3$ in a similar way.